# Json to CSV issues

Tags: json, pandas, export-to-csv, jq

I am using pandas to normalize some json data.  I am getting stuck on this issue when more than 1 section is either an object or an array.

If i use the record_path on Car it breaks on the second.

Any pointers on how to get something like this to create a line in the csv per Car and per Location?

```
[
    {
        "Name": "John Doe",
        "Car": [
            "Car1",
            "Car2"
        ],
        "Location": "Texas"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Jane Roe",
        "Car": "Car1",            
        "Location": [
            "Illinois",
            "Kansas"
        ]
    }
]
```

Here is the output

```
Name,Car,Location
John Doe,"['Car1', 'Car2']",Texas
Jane Roe,Car1,"['Illinois', 'Kansas']"
```

Here is the code:

```
with open('file.json') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)
df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(data, errors='ignore')
```

Would like it to end up like this:

```
Name,Car,Location
John Doe,Car1,Texas
John Doe,Car2,Texas
Jane Roe,Car1,Illinois
Jane Roe,Car1,Kansas
```

The answers worked great until I ran into a json file with extra data. This what a file looks like with the extra values.

```
{
    Customers:[
    {
        "Name": "John Doe",
        "Car": [
            "Car1",
            "Car2"
        ],
        "Location": "Texas",
        "Repairs: {
            "RepairLocations": {
                "RepairsCompleted":[
                    "Fix1",
                    "Fix2"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Name": "Jane Roe",
        "Car": "Car1",            
        "Location": [
            "Illinois",
            "Kansas"
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Here is what I am going for. I think its the most readable in this format but anything would at least should all the keys

```
Name,Car,Location,Repairs:RepairLocation
John Doe,Car1,Texas,RepairsCompleted:Fix1
John Doe,Car1,Texas,RepairsCompleted:Fix2
John Doe,Car2,Texas,RepairsCompleted:Fix1
John Doe,Car2,Texas,RepairsCompleted:Fix2
Jane Roe,Car1,Illinois,
Jane Roe,Car1,Kansas,
```

Any suggestions on getting this second part?

Comment: is this a python or jq question?

Comment: I am using jq and python to try and get the output I am looking for.

I used jq to get the data before I normalized it.

I added jq in case there was a way to fix it that way before normalizing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for something like this:

```
def expand($keys):
    . as $in
    | reduce $keys[] as $k ( [{}];
        map(. + { 
            ($k): ($in[$k] | if type == "array" then .[] else . end)
        })
    ) | .[];
(.[0] | keys_unsorted) as $h
| $h, (.[] | expand($h) | [.[$h[]]]) | @csv
```

<sup>[REPL demo](https://jqplay.org/s/vbXq4wojZE)</sup>

Comment: This worked great until I ran into some files with extra information.

Comment: Do you have any ideas for the issue I ran into?

Answer (score 1):

A simple jq solution which is also a bit more generic than needed here:

```
["Name", "Car", "Location"],
(.[]
 | [.Name] + (.Car|..|scalars|[.]) + (.Location|..|scalars|[.]))
| @csv
```