# JQ to CSV issues

Tags: json, export-to-csv, jq

I previously got some help on here for some jq to csv issues.  I ran into an issue where a few json files had some extra values that breaks the jq command

Here is the json data.  The repairs section is what breaks the jq command

```
[
    {
        "Name": "John Doe",
        "Car": [
            "Car1",
            "Car2"
        ],
        "Location": "Texas",
        "Repairs: {
            "RepairLocations": {
                "RepairsCompleted":[
                    "Fix1",
                    "Fix2"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Name": "Jane Roe",
        "Car": "Car1",            
        "Location": [
            "Illinois",
            "Kansas"
        ]
    }
]
```

Here is the command

```
def expand($keys):
    . as $in
    | reduce $keys[] as $k ( [{}];
        map(. + { 
            ($k): ($in[$k] | if type == "array" then .[] else . end)
        })
    ) | .[];
(.[0] | keys_unsorted) as $h
| $h, (.[] | expand($h) | [.[$h[]]]) | @csv
```

This is the end result i am trying to get. This data isnt actual data.

```
Name,Car,Location,Repairs:RepairLocation
John Doe,Car1,Texas,RepairsCompleted:Fix1
John Doe,Car1,Texas,RepairsCompleted:Fix2
John Doe,Car2,Texas,RepairsCompleted:Fix1
John Doe,Car2,Texas,RepairsCompleted:Fix2
Jane Roe,Car1,Illinois,
Jane Roe,Car1,Kansas,
```

Any advice on this would be great.  I am struggling to figure jq out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution can be obtained using the same technique shown in one of the answers to the [similar question you already asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60674867/json-to-csv-issues).  The only difference is fulfilling your requirements in the case where the "Repairs" key does not exist:

```
["Name", "Car", "Location", "Repairs:RepairLocation"],
(.[]
 | [.Name]
    + (.Car|..|scalars|[.])
    + (.Location|..|scalars|[.])
    + (.Repairs|..|scalars
       | [if . == null then . else "RepairsCompleted:\(.)" end]) )
| @csv
```

### Avoiding the repetition with a helper function

```
def s: .. | scalars | [.];
```

```
["Name", "Car", "Location", "Repairs:RepairLocation"],
(.[]
 | [.Name] 
    + (.Car|s)
    + (.Location|s) 
    + (.Repairs|s|map(if . == null then . else "RepairsCompleted:\(.)" end)))
| @csv
```

Comment: Thank you!  I was not sure on if I needed to ask a new one or not since it was already answered.  I am not quite familiar with jq.

Do you have any suggestions on a good place to learn to use this?